# How to use IF within FILTER for multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I'm trying to filter a range on one or multiple criteria. I have two cells where I can enter one or more criteria. The filtering works when a value is entered into all of the criteria cells, but if I leave one of them blank and only want to filter on just one criteria then it gives an error.

`=FILTER(RANGE, if(CRITERIA1<>"",COL1=CRITERIA1) ,REGEXMATCH(COL2, CRITERIA2))`

I want to add more criteria as the range has more columns, but I want to get it working with just two criteria for now. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

use query:

```
=QUERY(A:B, "where 1=1 "&
 IF(A1="",," and Col1 = '"&A1&"'")
 IF(B1="",," and Col2 = '"&B1&"'"), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible using FILTER? I had an issue with QUERY once before where it left out data and I'm a bit cautious about using it.